# What age group did Tolkien write The Hobbit for?

Tags: the-hobbit, j-r-r-tolkien, tolkiens-legendarium

Tolkien wrote *The Hobbit* as a story for children. However, I've never seen a specific age mentioned. Did Tolkien intend the story for young children or for teens?

**What reading level should a child be at to understand and enjoy *The Hobbit*?**

Comment: I don't remember where I read it, but I don't think Tolkien intended it to be for children. He did read it to his children, though...

Comment: I read the Hobbit when I was in second grade, and it's actually what started me down a long road of being an anti social bookworm. That said, I also read it last year (26 years old) and it was still quite enjoyable!

Comment: He did however say he regretted writing (was that the word? I think so but unable to check now and probably not any time soon) it or considering it as a book for children. In one of the letters at the very least. But it seems that this was after the fact. And as noted by @Wade he did read to his children. The question is was it meant to be a book for children or did it just happen to be that in reality? Also did he regret it if he made it for children? But it's a light read really and if 5 year olds read Harry Potter...

Comment: @Pryftan Yes, he did realise after the fact that it was more suited for children, and got quite upset. I think it's indeed in one of his letters. This is partly why he tried to make Lord of the Rings much darker

Comment: @Wade Yes I remember it that way too. I could easily find the letter too if I were to open the book - but I have too much going on/too tired to bother. I don't recall that being why he made The Lord of the Rings darker at least not by itself and perhaps there were many reasons behind it. I'm currently too knackered to think about it but I did always find it interesting, amusing and sort of ironic that he wasn't pleased it was suggested to be for children; it was as if he had made an error when in reality it's a wonderful book no matter what target anyone considers it to be.

Comment: @Pryftan Yeah - I was always very sad and bewildered he felt that way. It's a wonderful book, and it's suitable for all ages, even if it's a bit "childish". I think in many ways it's a lot nicer than his more "serious" works...

Comment: @Wade It never bothered me but I did admit I was baffled by the idea. It is a lovely book yes; I enjoy all his works equally though - they're different but it must be remembered that when he wrote Hobbit it wasn't meant to have a sequel and he delayed the sequel too after it was requested. So it was a very different universe then. So it's expected that it's 'different'.

Comment: @Pryftan I see what you mean... Maybe in any case he would have written something different. But all in all all the tales from "Tales from the Perilous Realm" are much more similar to the Hobbit; maybe he'd have written something like that if it weren't for these comments...

Comment: @Wade Had another death in the family this year... Anyway: **'Who can tell?' said Pryftan. [...]** Well maybe not. But whatever the case we can all speculate, we can all presume or even assume, but the bottom line is he regretted the idea that it was for children. I want to say part of it was something to do with the intelligence (or some such) of children but I'm uncertain; either way it's interesting why he would feel that way when e.g. Christopher hardly fit that category.

Comment: @Pryftan Sorry to hear that... And I guess he felt that people saying it was for children must have meant that it wasn't complicated, which he didn't like... Or something similar to this...

Comment: @Wade Thank you for that. He had a long great life and that is what we remember for comfort. But who knows with this subject - I am curious but I doubt we will ever know. Anyway thanks. Every life is precious and Tolkien understood that all to well. And Pity too. E.g. Gollum.

Comment: @Pryftan Yeah... He even had one chapter about an Orc going through the war, which I think people tend to forget about... Anyway, my condolences.

Comment: @Wade Thank you! :) What book are you referring to? The Hobbit? I could easily find it if I know what book but the way you describe it makes me uncertain; otoh he says in the letters that even Orcs weren't wholly evil.

Comment: Just to point out with the question itself: it seems to me that although you wonder in the title what age group did Tolkien write it for you also ask what age should a child be able to read it. Well I would say the two things are very different. That doesn't make it an invalid question but I feel it should be noted because it doesn't matter to a reader if he intended it for children as long as they read it okay and enjoy it.

Comment: @Pryftan That's true and I should have written the question differently. This question is 7 years old and the site standards have evolved over the years. If it were asked now, I'm sure it would been broken up into two questions. But the top three answers all address both questions to various degrees. It's difficult to answer the question about his intent without considering the books actual reading level. And as many have noted, the vocabulary of a 8yo English child in 1930 is very different than that of a 8yo American child in 2018.

Comment: @Memnoch Well you can never get things 'perfect' anyway :) You can refine and refine until you go absolutely mad. And 'should' often isn't reality (how ironic that going to the extreme and never being satisfied with your work can drive you mad and although perhaps not the same context ... well losing touch with reality). But what I was trying to say is his intent or not doesn't change the readability of the story one way or another; I agree with your statement though in some way or another. And it's not just American...

Comment: @Pryftan I was referring to a chapter in Lord of the Rings, told from the p.o.v. of an orc. I think there was one...

Comment: @Wade Unless you mean the chapter (2?) in The Two Towers book I (The Uruk-Hai) I don't think so and even that one is more from Pippin and Merry; otoh maybe you mean when Sam overhears the Orcs quarrelling in The Return of the King when he's trying to get to Frodo.I can think of other chapters the Orcs talk though but not from their p.o.v. I would say. Anyway, that would be interesting!

Comment: @Wade I just posted an analysis of his intentions and his opinions etc. in my own answer that you might like.

Comment: @Pryftan It was in the Lord of the Rings, but maybe not an entire chapter, but just one passage. I can't seem to find it... How vexing! I am sure there was such a passage...

Comment: @Wade I recently read it once again (do so at least once a year) but I don't recall this. I would have to think on it. I can think of a few passing moments where Orcs indeed are the 'narrator' (for want of a better word). Wait...unless you mean where Sam observes human versus human combat and how he didn't like it and he thought maybe the man really didn't want to be there but he was manipulated into? Not an Orc of course but...you say combat and his PoV. I would have to think more though or have more information on what you're thinking of. Again unless you mean the Uruk-Hai chapter?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

When Tolkien began writing The Hobbit in 1930, his children were 13, 10, 6, and 1, and he finished it two years later, so if the story that he wrote it for his own children is true, then presumably he hoped his two oldest children would enjoy it.

According to [wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_hobbit#Concept_and_creation):

> In a 1955 letter to W. H. Auden, Tolkien recollects that he began work on The Hobbit one day early in the 1930s, when he was marking School Certificate papers. He found a blank page. Suddenly inspired, he wrote the words, "In a hole in the ground there lived a hobbit." By late 1932 he had finished the story and then lent the manuscript to several friends, including C. S. Lewis and a student of Tolkien's named Elaine Griffiths. In 1936, when Griffiths was visited in Oxford by Susan Dagnall, a staff member of the publisher George Allen & Unwin, she is reported to have either lent Dagnall the book or suggested she borrow it from Tolkien. In any event, Miss Dagnall was impressed by it, and showed the book to Stanley Unwin, who then asked his 10-year-old son Rayner to review it. Rayner's favourable comments settled Allen & Unwin's decision to publish Tolkien's book.

So a contemporary 10 year old was able to enjoy the book. If you're trying to ascertain whether your child would be able to enjoy it, you should probably consider whether he knows a high enough percentage of the vocabulary to really understand it. The story of The Hobbit is not especially complicated - it's the language that is difficult. As I recall, studies have shown that as long as children know approximately 85% of the vocabulary in a book, they will have no difficulty filling in the rest from context. (Though I have long since sold back that psych textbook, and I can't seem to find a statistic online.)

Comment: I read it at 12 and loved it. If you have doubts though maybe you could read it to them. Honestly children of 9 and 10 are not too old to be read to and it makes for great family time.

Comment: My dad read it to me over a series of nights when I was 5 or 6, and reportedly I enjoyed it. (I say reportedly because my own memories of this are vague, although I do remember being terrified by the spiders in Mirkwood.)

Comment: I read at 8 or 9, as did most of my friends. My younger siblings read or had it read to them by the time they were 10. One of my brothers had the entire Lord of the Rings trilogy finished by 10, so as long as the child is a good reader, they can enjoy it.

Comment: My six year old loved it!  We did read it together and took turns with the reading so she could ask questions if she needed to along the way - but she got far more than I expected her to and even picked up references to some of the myths and Legends she has studied for history.

Comment: My daughter is 10, in 4th grade but has about a 7th grade reading level, and she read it and enjoyed it.  The last 1/4th or so though (once they arrive at the lonely mountain) is much more LOTR-esque language, and slowed her way down.

Comment: Great answer.  I would only add this:  The education system in Britain in the 30's was heavily focused on the classics, and as a result, kids who attended those schools could read at a much more advanced level than kids today, especially in the U.S. Advanced readers from late elementary school on should be able to handle it pretty well, but the average elementary school kid - again, especially in the U.S.- will probably have a much harder time.  The relative decrease in reading comprehension is compounded by the fact that Tolkien was a philologist, and was prone to using obscure words.

Comment: I read lord of the rings at 8 years old. We didn't have a TV in our house.

Comment: Although maybe he began writing it in 1930 I'm pretty sure some of it was created before in the late 1920s; I want to say this was in HoMe but it might not be the story itself (as for why in HoMe the best I can think of is it had to do with either the Ring or the relation between Hobbit and The Lord of the Rings albeit later on when the latter was thought about).

Comment: In my school here in Australia it was a class text for year 8 or 9, so roughly for age 13-14. This was in the late 90s. Needless to say, I read it in year 3 :-P

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the 10 year old Raynor Unwin ended the first ever review of *The Hobbit* (referred to in this answer) with "it should appeal to all children between the ages of 5 and 9."

Answer (score 9):

> At what reading level should a child be to understand and enjoy The Hobbit?

The lore states that The Hobbit was written as a story by Tolkien for his children, but it is unclear if he intended them to read it themselves or be read to.

In any event, The Hobbit is not too challenging in terms of writing, and there is enough action and adventure with little in the way of dry, dusty passages which can appear in LOTR. I'd say that any child who has read books like the Narnia series would be able to move onto The Hobbit. Even if a child doesn't understand all of the words, children by the age of 10 can easily learn mostly from context, and as long as there is a willing parent nearby to help with the rest, then there should be no problem.

The various adventures and "action" sequences are well-spaced to keep moderate attention spans occupied, too.

For the record - I was 9/10 when I first read the Hobbit (I'd already read the Narnia books at 7 and 8), and I read the Lord of the Rings almost right after (although, that took me a couple of months or so). The librarian aid it was for 12 years old.

Comment: What you say is true - any child could read it. I read The Chronicles of Narnia (all seven) at 5 and it was my introduction to fantasy. Didn't read Tolkien until years later but for some years now I read The Lord of the Rings at least once a year (the past two years twice each though this year has been quite different so that unsure on >1). I often throw in The Hobbit and various others (parts of HoMe for example; UT; Silmarillion; etc). Of course some kids would look words up and rarer are those like me who (and still enjoy) read the dictionary as a textbook!  Your point is valid either way.

Answer (score 6):

While it appears your question about Tolkien's intentions for the book itself seem to have been answered, I thought I would address the reading level aspect of the book.

Reading level is determined by vocabulary and sentence structure complexity and actually does not generally consider the content itself at all.  The Lexile framework score for *The Hobbit* is 1000, which puts it at a reading level more diffficult and higher than most of the Harry Potter books, Hunger Games and many other children's and young adult fiction using the same reading level scoring system.  This is partially because some of the vocabulary is not current with our modern usage of the words so the reading level expectation has probably gone up simply because of changes in the way we speak even in the not-quite 100 years since Tolkien was working on the story.  Using an AR score (which stands for Accelerated Reader and is a different system for measuring reading challenge level) it is considered a level 7 which puts it at the same level as *Door in the Wall*, and *Bridge to Terabithia*.  RL scoring (Reading Level) which is the older measure for reading challenge says it should be read at about ninth or tenth grade.

Having said all that, since none of those measures truly consider content.  I think they are all a bit "off."  The story, in my opinion, and based on the experience of many as well as Tales of Tolkien's intentions himself, is that the book is written for a younger audience than any reading level score comes up with.  Therefore, my suggestion is to read it together and enjoy it.  Kids will often understand a much greater amount of a story when it is read to them, than when they have to read it by themselves.  It is a bonding experience for the both of you, helps kids fall in love with books (as it is an awesome story) and *The Hobbit* is light-hearted enough that your average 2nd or 3rd grader would probably enjoy it very much if he/she didn't have to read it alone.  If you have an advanced reader, take turns reading your child can read some, but you'll be there to help and you'll be there for your turn to give your child a break.

I am currently reading the book for a second time with my seven year old.  We read it to her when she was five as well and she remembers it well.  Admittedly, she has an awesome vocabulary for a kid her age, but has absolutely no problem engaging in discourse about what has happened in the story.  She still isn't keen on reading it out loud to others (our babysitter joined us for last night's family read and she wouldn't take a turn reading aloud) but she loves the story and is always excited to read on and even said, "It's still exciting and fun" when it was pointed out that she already knew the end.  So, have fun!

Comment: This is an interesting perspective. As you mention, the reading level expectation has probably gone up due to the shift in modern vocabulary. Is there any information regarding what the estimated reading level expectation was at the time it was published?

Comment: @phantom42, I don't know, however, I too, heard he had his children in mind when writing it and I believe Unwin's son was about ten when he read it (recollections from watching a special feature about the publishing of the books and an interview with Unwin on the matter).

Comment: As another comparison, Wind in the Willows, with its talking animals and youthful adventures is measured at a lexile of 1140 when looking at an unabridged version - no book by, Ray Bradbury, Aldous Huxley or Frank Herbert are ranked as higher than that (though HG Wells and Orwell both have a couple that come "in range").  Clearly Reading Level may be a good way to measure how challenging vocabulary and sentence structure will be, but not appropriateness of subject matter for the age group at hand.

Comment: Interesting; I had never heard of lexile levels. What I find more interesting though is that if The Hobbit is at 1000 ... how on Earth is The Silmarillion 1150L? I don't know how it works so that might be part of it but if 2000 is the max (supposedly it is) ... The Hobbit is incredibly simple and esp compared to The Silmarillion (though I personally had no problem getting through it). Even so I think that this is probably only somewhat of a guideline but I suppose it's better than nothing. Anyway very interesting and +1 for that.

Comment: Okay even more baffling is this: The Fellowship of the Ring is at 860L; The Two Towers is at 810L and The Return of the King is at 920L. The Lord of the Rings is not an easier read than The Hobbit and I don't think anyone who has read both would think otherwise. That seems very odd and makes me question the system...

Answer (score 4):

I remember reading somewhere that the Hobbit was for his children, and LotR was also for his children, and was therefore 3-4 years more adult, as his children were growing up. However, it is probably valid to argue that the children of an Oxford English professor might have a slightly higher reading ability than average.

So I would say it was written for well read and educated 10-12 year olds - I think he was looking at his older children initially.

As to what age it should be read at today, I would say that any young teen or pre-teen should be able to give it a go, depending on their personal reading maturity. Much under this and they may not have the understanding ( of the ideas, not just the words ) to really appreciate and enjoy it.

Comment: I don't think even a 5 year old should have a problem reading it and certainly not enough to not enjoy it. Maybe not every 5 year old but many those age don't enjoy reading or haven't bothered with reading. Alternatively they might not like fantasy... Not saying you're wrong on a whole though. But it was initially for his children and later on he hinted that he regrets it being for children (something along those lines).

Comment: Another comment rereading your answer and my comment: I read The Chronicles of Narnia - all seven - when I was 5; and I really don't think The Hobbit is any more difficult than Narnia. Maybe this was my reading ability but either way it's going to vary from child to child. I have a teenage cousin who isn't interested in Hobbit or The Lord of the Rings because he seems to not understand that the films came much, much later (and are terrible; if he were to read the books he would understand that it's so much better and it's the films that are the problem).

Answer (score 4):

I read it the first time when I was about 12 and read it to my daughter the first time when she was about 5 or 6 and she loved it and had no problem following and understanding the story. I'm sure it all depends on the child, of course.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than write about what level should someone be at to understand and enjoy *reading* The Hobbit I would like to talk about what the title asks - but in a different way. I would like to add though that even if one cannot read I would say that if it was read by a parent (or sibling or someone else) to a child they would still enjoy it as long as it's their type of story (I want to say that if it isn't there is something wrong with them but I won't go there).

*Originally it was meant to be for children but he later had regrets about the tone and style;* he talks about this in a number of letters. Let's start with the first one being #131 (note that I have made bold my points whereas there are occasions where he made text italic):

> The generally different tone and style of *The Hobbit* is due, in point of
>   genesis, to it being taken **by me** as a matter from the great cycle
>   susceptible of treatment as a 'fairy-story', **for children.** Some of the
>   details of tone and treatment, I now think, **even on that basis, mistaken.
>   But I should not wish to change much.** For in effect **this is a study of
>   simple ordinary man, neither artistic nor noble and heroic** (but not without
>   the undeveloped seeds of these things) against a high setting - and in fact (as
>   a critic has perceived) the tone and style change with the Hobbit's development,
>   passing from fairy-tale to the noble and high relapsing with the return.

So here you can clearly see that it is a simple story in his mind; however he
does seem also to regret the tone and style. But why is that the case? Although
it seems odd he does explain it (and the explanation is odd too in my view). He
has a bit to say about not being careful in *The Hobbit* in letter #153; however
the next piece that shows where his thinking is is in #163. Here he talks in
this paragraph the way The Lord of the Rings was originally quite unconnected to
it but he also talks about the tone/style:

> It **was unhappily really meant, as far as I was conscious, as a
>   'children's story'**, and as **I had not learned sense** then, and **my children
>   were not quite old enough to correct me**, it has some of the sillinesses[sic]
>   of manner **caught unthinkingly from the kind of stuff I had had served to me**,
>   as a Chaucer may catch a minstrel tag. **I deeply regret them. So do intelligent
>   children.**

But clearly his latter assessment isn't true; intelligence doesn't really have a
play here does it? The best I can think of is that something happened in his
head once he was working on The Lord of the Rings (this letter, incidentally,
was posted on 7 June 1955) but this is mere speculation on my part. In letter #165 he has this brief bit to say and I think here we might finally have the
answer as to why he regrets the tone and style:

> **My work did not 'evolve' into a serious work. It started like that.** The
>   **so-called 'children's story'** *[The Hobbit]* was a fragment, torn out of an
>   already existing mythology. In so far as it was dressed up as **'for
>   children'**, in style or manner, I regret it. So do the children. I am a
>   philologist, and all my work is philological. I avoid hobbies because I am a
>   very serious person and cannot distinguish between private amusement and duty. I
>   am affable, but unsociable. I only work for private amusement, since I find my
>   duties privately amusing.

So it seems to me that he had an issue with seriousness and lack thereof.
Perhaps he was conscious of some critique? He did make clear that he was the
most critical of his work out of all critics but I suppose that's how we all
are, whether we know it or not. Letter #215 has some more interesting bits on
why he might have wrote it the way he did:

> The relation between *The Hobbit* and its sequel is I think this. *The Hobbit*
>   is a first essay or introduction (consideration will admit I think that it is
>   very just point at which to begin the narration of the subsequent events) to a
>   complex narrative which had been brewing in my mind for years. **It was overtly
>   addressed to children for two reasons: I had at that time children of my own and
>   was accustomed to making up (ephemeral) stories for them; I had been brought up
>   to believe that there was a real and special connexion between children and
>   fairy-stories.** Or rather to believe that this was a received opinion of my
>   world and of publishers. I doubted it, since it did not accord with my personal
>   experience of my own taste, nor with my observation of children (notably my
>   own). But the convention was strong.

It seems pretty clear from the above that he had mixed feelings on it; certainly
he wanted to believe he was wrong to target children despite the fact **he made
up stories for his own children.** He goes on to say that it builds up into more
serious or significant and more consistent and historical but he regrets it all
the same. Yet at the time there wasn't meant to be any relation to it and The
Lord of the Rings (as it wasn't conceived) so there is some inconsistency here
too. He was asked what his definition of what children are. He goes on to say
that we all need literature that is above our measure although we might not have
sufficient energy for it at the time. He suggests this too:

> Therefore do not write down to Children or to anybody. Not even in language.
>   Though it would be a good thing if that great reverence which is due to children
>   took the form of eschewing the tired and flabby cliches of adult life. But an
>   honest word is an honest word, and its acquaintance can only be made by meeting
>   it in a right context. A good vocabulary **is not required by reading books
>   written according to some notion of the vocabularly of one's age-group. It comes
>   from reading books above one.**

I found that very intriguing because it seems contradictory to what he was
talking about in the first place. But letter #234 is very interesting on the
subject of children and childishness. This is about The Lord of the Rings:

> It was *not* written 'for children', or for any kind of person in particular,
>   **but for itself.** (If any parts or elements in it appear 'childish', it is
>   because I am childish, and like that thing *now*.)

In this letter he has something interesting to say on vocabulary:

> Children are not a class or kind, they are a heterogeneous collection of
>   immature persons, varying, as persons do, in their reach, and in their ability
>   to extend it when stimulated. **As soon as you limit your vocabularly to what
>   you suppose to be within your reach, you in fact simply cut off the gifted ones
>   from the chance of extending it.**

Finally in letter #257 he says that he told (often orally) many stories to his children
all unpublished - and that The Hobbit was meant to be one of them. And what a
loss that would have been...

So in summary I think we can conclude that:

1. He clearly wrote it for children.
2. He believed however that one shouldn't write to children or any age group as
   such, in a way.
3. He actually at one point enjoyed the childishness but he seemed to be at odds
   of this at times (since he said his work started out serious as he takes his
   life seriously).
4. He believes intelligent children wouldn't appreciate Hobbit.
5. But in any case whether or not he intended to write it for children (which he
   admitted he did) he still regretted it yet somehow had mixed feelings on it. I
   think we can all speculate on how this all interconnects but I don't think it
   says anything on the reading level targeted or whether children would enjoy it;
   these are just his regrets and thoughts on the work after the fact. And he was
   his worst critic for certain. Children do enjoy it, always have and I believe always will, regardless of what he felt. It was also written for children even though he was at times at odds with this.

Comment: A very interesting collection of letters... How odd that he felt so harshly about such a wonderful book! "I avoid hobbies because I am a very serious person and cannot distinguish between private amusement and duty." - what a weird thing to say! What can be wrong with writing stories with a light tone? I understand what he says about vocabulary ("As soon as you limit your vocabulary to what you suppose to be within your reach, you in fact simply cut off the gifted ones from the chance of extending it"), but I don't think The Hobbit's vocabulary is really aimed for children...

Comment: @Wade I seem to recall that he talks more about his idea here but I'm not sure what letter it is. I agree: it is very odd and it seems baffling too. And let's say it was originally for children (I would argue that in many respects it is and he even regrets it which means actually *it was intended for children - at first*) does it make a difference, truly? His idea that intelligent children wouldn't want it that way is I believe flatly false. Of course I would argue the question itself doesn't mean much as far as who can enjoy it or who can understand it. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @Wade I actually had another thought on it reading part of my answer: maybe the reason he didn't like the fact it was for children is that he felt by limiting it for children it made it less wonderful? **As soon as you limit your vocabularly to what you suppose to be within your reach, you in fact simply cut off the gifted ones from the chance of extending it.** I really haven't a clue but in the end he seems really rather mixed on it so who can tell? I would argue he simply changed his mind and that's more than fair. Of course for the question - what it *was* intended for - it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

I read the hobbit at 7 years old and continued to read it for many years to come, as it was part of my favourite collection. Even now, I still have the same book and it is still my favourite story. :)  And I will surely give it to my kids as well. It teaches that good triumphs over evil, and it was inspiring for me to learn those values at a young age. Now I can't wait for the Hobbit movie to hit cinemas. :)

Answer (score -1):

I didn't read *The Hobbit* until I was thirteen, but I probably would have been able to read and enjoy it years earlier.

If I remember correctly, I was given and read *Bent's Fort* by David Lavender a few years earlier, and I suppose that it was considered a somewhat more gown up type of book.

[1] [http://www.amazon.com/Bents-Fort-David-Lavender/dp/0803257538](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0803257538)
 [1]:

On summer vacation when I was twelve I read *The Wizard of OZ* and a book of short stories including Poe's "The Murders in the Rue Morgue", so I read stories written for widely different age groups.

The minimum age to use the adult section of the local library was sixteen, but I began using it when I was fourteen.

So I think that I could have read *The Hobbit* by myself and enjoyed it several years before I was thirteen.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of what age **Tolkien** wrote the Hobbit for.